# What does the Super Nitrous do in CSR Racing 2?

Tags: android, csr-racing-2

I have been playing CSR2 for a little while, and have recently defeated the Tier 1 leader, KJ. However, afterwards he challenged me to a race where I wager the gold I won from beating him for his car. I chose to take him up on it, and then I was told I'd have no hope without first getting Super Nitrous - which costs real money. So I brought it and managed to win the car from KJ.

What I want to know is, does the Super Nitrous stay, and if so what does it do... Or is it only for the races where you're racing for the cars of those you have beaten?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my experience with these kind of racing games on mobile devices it is almost assured that this super nitrous boost is not permanent and only lasts a short amount of time. I couldn't tell you the specific amount of time but many similar games last around 10 minutes or for that specific race.

**Edit**

After looking through a lot of posts on reddit about the super nitrous it will **only last for the boss races**, and that is it. After that it goes away meaning you'd have to buy it again for future boss races.

Wiki states about super nitrous:

> Boost nitrous is a more powerful, special nitrous that can only be obtained during a high stakes boss race. The agent will ask the player to buy it, noting that the crew leader will be a lot harder. It does cost real money and the player may choose to decline. However, it is very powerful.

Source: http://csrracing.wikia.com/wiki/Parts

Comment: Yeah I fixed that now, shortly after I posted I did find out that the super nitrious in question is a one time deal. Thanks.

Comment: I'm working on that, unsurprisingly most of the searches you get for this game's super nitrious is how to do these races without it.

Comment: Even if all you can find are players discussing it, if you can find multiple places where people say that it is a one-time thing, you could use all of them as evidence. Just a tip.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I am still getting used to answering stuff on here so I appreciate it. The wiki did confirm the one time use too.

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe it's a single use thing, though... I feel swindled out now that I know. Anyway, enjoy the bounty.

Comment: @Auro I am kind of shocked by that too, I have done a lot of reading and a lot of people recording you fully upgrade your care before attempting those races since they most certainly are beatable without the super nitrous.

Comment: Well, that is indeed true. I upgraded my Tier 1 car to the max, and it preforms better than the Tier 2 boss car I won from KJ. So I guess the best advice is to max out a car before taking on the third race against a boss.

Answer (score 0):

I have found if you buy the SuperNitrous and lose, you get another race to try again up to 3 times, after which if you happen to lose all 3, you get the boss car anyway. I did this to get Kiyiya's Silvia. So basically, you are buying the car for whatever the nitrous costs ($4.99?)

Comment: Do NOT purchase based on what David Orifice said! YOU DO NOT GET MULTIPLE ATTEMPTS!

Comment: I beg to differ David, but I DID win Kiyiya's Sylvia after losing the race using the Super Nitrous. I DID get 3 attempts which I lost and was given the car anyway. I did not and am not suggesting to pay for the Super Nitrous to get the car. I just stated my experience. I have been, in fact using the information I have found in searches to better my times to win the boss cars legit, w/o Super Nitrous.